# Amazon S3 REST API incorrect size

Tags: javascript, rest, file-upload, amazon-s3, filereader

I'm trying to implement an HTML5 Amazon S3 uploader (by using the REST API), and stumbled upon the following issue: when trying to upload a small, text file, everything works like a charm. When trying to upload a binary file, the file gets bigger on S3, and, obviously, corrupted. Here's what I'm doing:

```
// multipart upload init / finish code hidden; if you need it, I'll add it
// file is read by using a file input
var blob = file.slice(start, end);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);

// in reader.onloadend:
var path = "/" + settings.key;

path += "?partNumber=" + chunk + "&uploadId=" + u.upload_id;
var method = "PUT";
var authorization = "AWS " + settings.access_key + ":" + signature;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, settings.host + path, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-amz-date", date);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authorization);

// application/octet-stream used
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", settings.content_type); 
xhr.send(e.target.result);
```

Also, I've tried to create a 10mb file with text (10 million lines of 0123456789) and that one works correctly.

If anyone has a solution to this problem, or stumbled upon it, let me know.

Comment: Hi do you have sample code for file uploading to amazon s3 using REST API in java..Please send me if you have it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems StackOverflow is also good for figuring things out yourself -- I've fixed it just as I finished putting my ideas down. It seems the `xhr.send()` method can receive the `file.slice()` blob directly, so no need for `FileReader`.

I hope this helps other people that stumble upon this issue.